# import js external file in angular 6

Tags: javascript, d3.js, angular6

Im working in a project in angular and i have to integrate D3JS in it, i used

```
npm install d3
```

and its working fine.
i need to use a function inside js file.. i followed some steps to import it, but still get error, here what i did:
I put the js file in the node module.
then i i added the path in angular.json file like this:

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js",
              "node_modules/d3/labeler.js"
            ]
```

and in the import i used this script:

```
import * as labeler from 'labeler.js';
```

then i add this declaration:

```
declare var labeler: any;
```

and in the end i want to use the function labeler that i developed inside the labeler.js in this way:

```
d3.labeler()
```

and i got this error:

```
[WDS] Warnings while compiling. client:147
./node_modules/labeler.js
4:16-26 "export 'labeler' (imported as 'd3') was not found in 'd3' client:153
./src/app/components/init-map-markers/init-map-markers.component.ts
916:8-18 "export 'labeler' (imported as 'd3') was not found in 'd3'
```

is there any one have an idea how to do it in the right way? thks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the types by hand, you can use the typings built and maintained by the community

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3 for the latest version
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-v4-typings for v4

Comment: the file, i wanted to add doesn't exist in D3 labrary, that's wahy im traying to tis way to do it, and already used npm install d3 --save, but waht i'm trying to do is to import a function in external file